# Cannot use object of type Product as array prestashop 1.7

Tags: smarty, prestashop, product

i have problem, when i change the declination on my product page on prestashop 1.7.1.1
when i looked for the error it look this [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zb9i.png)

any one can help me please, im using prestashop 1.7.1.1

Comment: Do not simply paste a picture. Please provide the relevant code and the applicable error message in a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), also see [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error: "Cannot use object of type Product as array".

In Prestashop 1.7: "Objects are no longer passed to Smarty. We only use arrays now." (http://build.prestashop.com/news/module-development-changes-in-17/#general-information)

In my case, it was a module 'productcomments'. He overwrites the "product" index and changes "array" to "object".

Comment: yes, its exactly this module who make all the problems, thank you very much for your answer

Answer (score 2):

It may be easy to solve.

The message says you are trying to use an object like an array

Imagine you want to fetch the id from the variable:

For arrays

`$product['id']`

But for objects

`$product->id`

So search in the template for the incorrect use of the product variable and fix it.